# List<>.AddRange - where clause

Tags: hyperlink, where-clause, addrange

Hi I am working on application to get some details from Sharepoint lists.
I am able to get the results as shown below:

```
sample.AddRange(queryResults.GetItemRows().Select(listItemRow => new CalendarEvents
                {
                    ItemId = listItemRow.ItemId,
                    Title = listItemRow.AttributeValueOrDefault("ows_Title", ""),
                    StartDate = listItemRow.AttributeValueOrDefault("ows_StartDate", ""),
                    EndDate = listItemRow.AttributeValueOrDefault("ows_EndDate",""),
                    Link = listItemRow.StrippedAttributeValueOrDefault("ows_Link", "")
                }).OrderBy(listItemRow => listItemRow.StartDate));
```

Where as I am struck at one point:
- I want to extract the list rows with future events. I mean StartDate should be >= present date. I tried some options but no success. I know I need to use .where at the end of AddRange, but how can I check the condition for the date.

I tried as below but didn't work

```
}).where(listItemRow => listItemRow.StartDate >= dateTime.now)
```

Any help would be great...

Thankx

Answer (score 0):

Have you make sure you had your data? Is there any error?

If not, try to use:

```
}).Where(listItemRow => listItemRow.StartDate.After(DateTime.Now));
```

Comment: Solved by changing it to the below code:

                }).Where(o => o.StartDate > DateTime.Now.Date));

Thankx for your help.